# Secuencia en ORACLE, como volver a un valor anterior o modificar su valor actual

Tags: oracle

Digamos que tengo esta secuencia

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "NOMBRE_DB"."MI_SECUENCIA"  MINVALUE 0 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 21 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
```

Y queremos consultar su estado para alterar su valor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seria de la siguiente forma, dentro de oracle hacemos estas consultas suponiendo que la secuencia va en 10 y va de 1 en 1 y queremos volver a 1, la secuencia debe tener como valor minimo 0.

Consulta para ver donde va la cuenta

```
select MI_SECUENCIA.nextval from dual;
```

Consulta para restar lo que se necesite para volver a 1 en este caso

```
alter sequence MI_SECUENCIA increment by -10;
```

Luego:

```
alter sequence MI_SECUENCIA increment by 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

select MI_SECUENCIA.nextval from dual;
esta sentencia aumenta el valor actual al siguiente.

para consultar el valor actual debe ser:
select MI_SECUENCIA.currval from dual;